# Programmatically Get Recommendations from LinkedIn University pages

Tags: linkedin-api

We have a requirement to get certain information (recommendations) from the LinkedIn University pages like https://in.linkedin.com/edu/insead-12445 . Is there any LinkedIn API feature which will help me to get information from custom pages? I can make a WebRequest to the URL to get data; however, I would rather implement a scalable option.

Regards Raghav

Comment: Please let me know if anyone has inputs on this. Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Anyone from LinkedIn support can help me ?Thanks